# System.Guid to _GUID?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have a c++ project that i'm trying to use from .net c#. The main problem is that in c++ i have something like

```
static const GUID guid ={ 0x4be732d4, 0x3244, 0x4ad3, { 0x92, 0xbd, 0xf2, 0x80, 0x9d, 0xf0, 0x96, 0xf6 } };
HRESULT ActivateItem(String^ Name, String^ Var )
{
    hr = Item->SetId(&guid);
    StartItem(&guid);
}

From C# would be ActivateItem("someName", "someVar");
```

I need to create the GUID in c# to use it in a DB but the System.Guid obvious is not the same with _GUID and im pretty bad at C++ .

Can anyone give a hand?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use this code on MSDN to solve your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb8scw8f.aspx

Comment: I didn't saw it im an idiot THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN supplies a handy tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb8scw8f.aspx) on how to do this, note that the code can also be used in C++/CLI when needed.

To convert from a _GUID:

```
System::Guid FromGUID(_GUID& guid) {  
   return System::Guid(guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3,   
                guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1],   
                guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],   
                guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5],   
                guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7] );  
}
```

To convert back to a _GUID:

```
_GUID ToGUID(System::Guid& guid) {  
   array<Byte>^ guidData = guid.ToByteArray();  
   pin_ptr<Byte> data = &(guidData[0]);    
   return *(_GUID*)data;  
}
```